# issues with importing large csv file to phpmyadmin with sql

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I've got a large (about 20MB) csv file I'm trying to import into a table in my database. The file has a little over 78,000 rows, and 26 columns. I only need the first few columns. I enter the following code into the sql terminal in phpmyadmin:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path to my file/myfile.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, name, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy)
```

It gives a successful message, which says, "156306 rows inserted. (Query took 8.2870 seconds.)" This is exactly double the number of rows the file has.

I went in to browse the table and see what happened, and phpmyadmin's browse window is indicating there are only 13264 records there. The rows that successfully imported worked perfectly. Since I'm using a replace to eliminate duplicates, I expected far fewer than the 78k rows, but many of the cases are missing. Any idea what might cause this issue? I've never experienced this before....

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to 150M and restart Apache.  Visit https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-extend-limit-of-import-file-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Change the value on this file `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf` using notepad or any other text editor. Increase `max_allowed_packet` as needed after u try to import the csv file. once again full document copy open new document paste and save it. don't save as page.

Comment: This does not appear to be the solution, unfortunately. max_allowed_packet was set to 1M by default. I changed it to 500M, restarted mysql, and tried the query again. It took 40 seconds instead of 8, but with the exact same results. I then changed it to 999M, restarted and tried again. This time it took 44 seconds, again with the same results.